# Get info about a workflow item using Documentum API calls

Tags: documentum

What is the API call to get information about the packages in a workflow based on the **package_id** of the workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what info are you specifically trying to retrieve.  The workflow info is stored across many different objects and can be hard to track down.  please post what your specifically trying to find and i might be able to help more.  as a start, these objects include:

- dm_workflow
- dmi_workitem
- dmi_wf_attachment

but there are others too.